# Adding Submatrix in Numpy without Loop

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I got this
`a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))` I want get a numpy array of `[9,12,15]` which is a result of

```
[0+3+6, 1+4+7, 2+5+8]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use`numpy.array.sum()` function by passing the `axis=0`:

```
>>> a.sum(axis=0)
array([ 9, 12, 15])
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `numpy.sum` function and specify the axis over which you want to sum, which is `0` in your case:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
a_sum = np.sum(a, axis=0)

print a_sum
```

This gives you:

```
[ 9 12 15]
```

The answer of Kasramvd uses the object-oriented approach, which some people prefer:

```
a_sum = a.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Many of the `np` functions try to use the array's own method.  So result is usually the same.